# How can I use structured references to a column in an Excel macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Here's an example that will explain things:

```
Sheets("Plot Data July").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tPDJuly").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tPDJuly").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4
```

So as you can see above, `Field:=2` is a relative reference to the second field in the table called "tPDJuly". So now if I add more columns, this number does not get updated. The field is actually called "Grade" in the table. So is there a way of coding this so that no matter which column it is in, "Grade" is always updated?

I suppose one solution is that we add a line that find what is the column number for "Grade"?

UPDATE: This is the full statement

```
Sheets("Plot Data July").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tPDJuly").Range.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="0"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tPDJuly").Range.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="J4"
```

where `Field:=4` is actually the Field `Exclude` in that table i.e. `tPDJuly[Exclude]` and similarly `Field:=2` is `Grade`

So I want to change these fixed references to `2` and `4`  into something more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

Dragging this thread back into life. I've been trying to achieve something myself today and through brute force and trial and error, I've found an answer that doesn't involve a messy select statement or having an activated sheet.

```
TableName.Range.Autofilter Field:=TableName.ListColumns("Column Name").Index, _
    Criteria1:="SearchString"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to select a column using the table properties with the following:

```
sheets("Plot Data July").select    
range("tPDJuly[Grade]").select
```

This should select your grade column.  The quotes seem to be important when concantenating the values into a reference.

If you want both columns, you'll need to change it a bit:

```
sheets("Plot Data July").select    
range("tPDJuly[Grade],tPDJuly[Column4]").select
```

Comment: So then that would be `Field:=range("tPDJuly[Grade]").select` ?

Comment: You shouldn't need Field: at all.

Comment: Then the solution would be `ActiveSheet.ListObjects("tPDJuly").Range.AutoFilter range("tPDJuly[Grade],tPDJuly[Column4]").select` ?

Comment: When I tried it on my test worksheet, I didn't need anything other than `range("tPDJuly[Grade],tPDJuly[Column4]").select` if I was on the sheet with the table.  Otherwise, I needed to add `sheets("Plot Data July").select` also.  I never needed to use `activesheet.listobjects().range.autofilter` at all.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work when you want to use criteria. Did you check the update to the question?

Comment: Sorry, was working off of our comments and didnt' see the update.  If you want to use Autofilter, then you'll need to return an integer for the field value. I don't have time to try this right now, but can you set a variable to capture the column number for Grade, and then pass the variable to the Field argument in Autofilter?

Comment: that would be a good solution I suppose. But no clue how to accomplish that! I'll mess around with it!